# Uncommitted work in tests / Preparing for callouts

Tags: unit-test, callout, dml, insert

I have the following scenario in some unit tests:

1. I need to create some data with inserts
2. I need to invoke a method which performs a callout

The test fails with the `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`. How do I commit the insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply searching that error message would yield some [highly useful information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003701&type=1):

> Sometimes a developer needs to create a record and then update it with information provided by a Web Service. However, a Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement within the same transaction. To achieve the required action, the transaction must be separated into two parts so that the DML transaction is completed before the Web Service Callout occurs.

So either invoke the callout before your DML operation, or split them out into separate transactions.

If the insertions are all just data setup, it should suffice to simply make sure the callout is between your `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` calls:

```
static testmethod void testSomeStuff()
{
    // set up test data
    // (insert is here)

    Test.startTest();
        // set mock
        // make callout
    Test.stopTest();

    // make assertions
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found that information. However no information/example is provided on how you split them into separate transactions

Comment: Why does your *test* need to make a callout? Can you give more context about what exactly you're testing? You could use `@future` or `Test.runAs(user)` but it's hard to know what would work for your situation since it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 1) I have built a layer that wraps a call to a  rest api 2) I have a service that needs to perform a) call the rest api b) update the account object.  3) this service is meant to be invoked from a RemoteController. I have a test of the layer that wraps the api and the test works correctly using the HttpCalloutMock, however if I place some inserts before the call it doesn't work. That's why I asked: how do I commit the work / split the transaction?

Comment: Are the insertions just test data setup? Calling `startTest` should suffice...

Comment: That works. Not only you need to startTest() but  you also need a Test.stopTest().

Comment: Yes, best practice would be to *always* wrap the functionality you are testing between these methods.